# Edit a file to be uploaded

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to be able to edit a file that has been selected for upload. I want to search and replace text in case absolute files should be made relative...

I notice in the File API I can do some of it, but I get a little stuck:

```
document.getElementById('exampleInputFile').onchange = function(event) {
  var fileToLoad = event.target.files[0];

  if (fileToLoad) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
      var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
      //Use logic to remove absolute files
      //Upload S3
    };
    reader.readAsText(fileToLoad, 'UTF-8');
  }
};
```

I am trying to figure out how now to convert that text to a proper File so that I can upload it to S3 using an existing api that expects something returned by: `event.target.files[0]` code above.

I do not want the server to handle any heavy lifting here if I can avoid it (files can easily be a few megabytes since they can be 3D models).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the url of the file when it lands in the S3 bucket, you can retrieve the file using a http.get, which will give you the contents of the (I assume plain text file). You can then parse that file and do whatever modification you need to do on the contents. If the file has changed, you can then write it back to the S3 bucket to replace the original file.

Comment: I would like to avoid the server being involved in this coding procedure and have the client handle the effort of parsing a file. It might for all I know be quite a few megabytes sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

On AWS you can use Lambda to execute NodeJS code when an event is triggered (for example an upload to a specified bucket).

Comment: Good point, I had forgotten about that, although @msj121 might prefer to have all his code in Meteor

Comment: This might work out as it avoid my server, but I would like to avoid using S3 itself in case I want to change servers, or change the coding for dev/production servers (I allow both to access the same S3 instance). I have posted part of a client version

Comment: Why you talked about S3 in your first post then?

Comment: The point was that I didn't want to process on the server. The file was to reside off-server was why I had mentioned it. I do like this solution, but I would prefer a client version if feasible, I have edited the question to reflect this. Sorry